Einstein–Podolsky–Rosen (EPR) paradox and Everett interpretation
Can Einstein–Podolsky–Rosen paradox be satisfactory explained outside of the Everett interpretation of QM?
Can it be easily explained within Everett interpretation?

"Can" - is a yes/no question. It would be better to rephrase the question as a "how".

EPR's point is not a paradox, but incompleteness of orthodox quantum theory.

All interpretations of Quantum Mechanics explain the Einstein-Podolsky-Rosen paradox by its own way. If it is "satisfactory" or "easily explained" is quite personal, and I would say that it could not be answered in any scientific basis.
The main point of the EPR paradox is the apparent tension behind the results predicted (and experimentally tested) by quantum theory and scientific realism, which is the assumption about systems possessing its own physical properties all the time, even without it being measured by any experiment or measurement procedure. The argument also is based on the Locality assumption, where physical systems could only interact locally, without "spooky action at a distance".
Since the discovery of Bell theorem, the discussion about EPR changed. We know that realism and locality together could not be assumed if one wants to apply it to explain quantum correlations. Since then, great part of physical community interpreted that the hypothesis of realism should be discarded.

I don't know about how many worlds interpretation deals with realism of physical quantities. But I can tell you that it is impossible to explain the data obtained in measurements over quantum system in a complete realistic perspective without some violation of locality principle.
